# Is it possible to activate a library on the pc using excel vba?

Tags: scripting, reference, libraries

I make excel files for other users in the company. However, sometimes the PCs are not configured identically and certain libraries are not activated. I'd like to activate them with a macro.

Up to now, I've told users to activate the library manually. It would be much more efficient to be able to activate it automatically when they use the file I've prepared for them.